# Office365 API App registration fails: Bad Request

Tags: oauth, office365, office365-apps

When registering an app at https://dev.office.com/Getting-Started/office365Apis, I get the following error:

```
The following error occurred while processing your request:
ERROR: Request_BadRequest - Invalid value found for property 'identifierUris' of resource 'Application'.
```

I have registered an another app successfully before with the same account. The URIs for my app are https.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to hear you're having trouble. Our team is investigating and will update this answer once we have it identified.

Is it possible to share the App Name and/or Redirect URI that your are using, as well as the platform chose? Understand if it's not. Are there any non-alpha numeric characters?

In the meantime, you can register your app manually through Azure AD. Here is how: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually got it registered. Seems like I wasn't able to use non-ascii characters in the name. Removing those solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it resolved. We'll add an item to our backlog to provide better error handling in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I mark this answer as accepted. The key point is non-alpha numeric characters. It would make sense to add a different error for the matter.